# Can't get SPAppWebUrl - SharePoint 2013

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, token

I'm developing an auto-hosted asp.net app for Sharepoint 2013. I have to use the SPAppWebUrl token value for my requests. So I tried this :

- AppManifest.xml : `<StartPage>~remoteAppUrl/Pages/Index.aspx?{StandardTokens}</StartPage>`
- javascript : 
  `var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));`
- C# code-behind : `Application["SPAppWebUrl"] = Request.QueryString["SPAppWebUrl"];`

Nothing worked. Sharepoint sends values for SPHostUrl, SPLanguage, SPClientTag and SPProductNumber only. I read [topics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163816.aspx) [about tokens](http://www.mavention.com/blog/sharePoint-app-reading-data-from-host-web) and noted this :

> If there is no app web, the portion &SPAppWebUrl={AppWebUrl} is not present.

But I dont understand how I could not have an app web...
If anybody can help please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I was using Provider Hosted.  The App Web for me wasn't coming over because I tried to use a certificate that would not work (wild card).  Went through the certificate setup a second time using a self-signed certificate - then setup a dummy list and when I looked at:

```
string spAppUrl = Request["SPAppWebUrl"];
```

I'm getting back the proper value.  I then use the URL to get your App web via:

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity currentUser = Request.LogonUserIdentity;

using (var appContext = TokenHelper.GetS2SClientContextWithWindowsIdentity(appUri, currentUser))
            {
                if (appContext != null)
                {
                    Web appWeb = appContext.Web;
                    appContext.Load(appWeb, w => w.Title);
                    appContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    string title = appWeb.Title;
                    ViewBag.SiteTitle = title;
                }
            }﻿
```

Answer (score 0):

Had exactly the same issue. The following blog post tells you how to resolve it:

[SP Rest Services with Provider hosted app](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/03/02/using-rest-services-with-a-provider-hosted-app-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Basically, since a provider-hosted app doesn't have and app web, you have to tell sharepoint to create it. You do this by adding a dummy object (site column, list, etc) to your SharePoint project. It will then create the app web and add SPAppWebUrl to the standard tokens (in the app manifest).